# Does having two installations of Wordpress negatively affect SEO?

Tags: seo

I found a similar thread [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/seo-two-wordpress-websites-on-same-domain-name) but it didn't seem to answer what I needed. Basically, I'm running a core wordpress install on " www.domain.com " One of the pages on that site needs to run on a completely different theme.

"www.domain.com/page1, /page2, /page2" would all be on the main theme.

"www.domain.com/coolpage" would be on the separate theme. Two cores and plugins, etc. is fine by me. I just want to know if it would negatively impact SEO

Comment: **SEO** questions are almost *never* specific to **WordPress**. This one is not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is designed so you should never need to have duplicate installs, even if you have thousands of sites across hundreds of domains.

With that in mind, I'm curious why, if you're just making one page different, you don't use a custom page template instead of the bloat of multiple installs?  It seems it would be much, much easier - just make a copy of `page.php`, rename it `page-coolpage.php`, and modify it to do exactly what you need.  WordPress is designed with that in mind, so it makes more sense to make use of the tools built in that throwing in a duplicate install.

Alternately, make your WordPress a multisite install, deploy the second theme on the coolpage site, and go from there.  Single dashboard = one place for updates, comment management, content management, and so on.  It's a little more complex than a custom page template, but it's less overhead and hassle than multiple installations of WordPress.

As someone who is cleaning up the mess left behind by someone doing exactly what you're thinking of doing (multiple installs), I assure you a custom page template or multisite setup is infinitely preferable to managing multiple installations.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't definitively answer this, but I can't imagine that it would - as long as you aren't duplicating content. Search engines aren't really looking at how a web page is built, more at the HTML output. So as long as your content isn't duplicate and your code structure is SEO friendly, I don't see a reason why this would hurt you.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no negative SEO impact because of that. Feel free to install new wp in that folder.

There is no reason to be penalised. Actually you can just benefit from that. You can submit XML sitemap and RSS feed from that site to Web Master Tools and FeedBurner, and then google will know that you have another site in that folder, and he is fine with that.

On the other hand, there are hundreds of WP-multiuser sites based on subfolders.